# Lookup operator to include partial on Handlebars

Tags: templates, dynamic, handlebars.js, lookup, partials

I've extensively searched for an answer to this, so I hope I haven't missed the obvious.

I'm using handlebars to iterate over an array of objects and choosing a partial view depending on a property on each object.

I have seen the documentation for dynamic partials as well as for the lookup operator and a number of explanations online but I can't seem to understand how the `.` and `..` are used or relate to the current context.

I would expect the following code

```
{{#each data as |item|}}
    {{> (lookup item 'type') }}
{{/each}}
```

to look for a type property on each object in the array and include a partial with that name, but the lookup evaluates to `undefined`.

I have seen examples showing this instead

```
{{> (lookup . 'property') }}
```

so my questions:

1. What's the right way to refer to `item` in the lookup?
2. What `.` and `..` refer to?

Thanks.

EDIT: Added data object and template from actual code (data object has been reduced and actual entity name changed to 'item' but otherwise actual code)

From the data

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": { "href": "/item/342" }
    },
    "itemId": "342",
    "datetime": "2012-10-06T04:13:00+00:00",
    "itemType": "ITEM_TYPE",
    "content": {
    }
},
```

From the template

```
{{#each data as |item|}}
    {{> (lookup item 'itemType') }}
{{/each}}
```

Error

```
{
    description: undefined,
    fileName: undefined,
    lineNumber: undefined,
    message: "The partial undefined could not be found",
    name: "Error"…
}
```

Comment: Your `#each` looks to me as though it should work. Perhaps if you shared your data object we could figure out what the issue is. `.` is alias for `this` and points to the currently scoped object. `../` points up one level to the parent scope's object.

Comment: @76484 Thanks. That's what I thought about `.` and `..` but somehow it didn't seem to work for me. I was expecting that either `item` or `.` would pass the correct object for lookup but it didn't. I added data and the error message.

Comment: Digging deeper i found that the controller was filtering out fields of the data before being passed to the template. The syntax does indeed work but I had to remap the `itemType` field for it to be visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution. As noted by @76484:

`.` is alias for `this` and points to the currently scoped object. `../` points up one level to the parent scope's object.

The lookup in the example can be done either by

```
{{#each data as |item|}}
    {{> (lookup item 'itemType') }}
{{/each}}
```

or

```
{{#each data}}
    {{> (lookup . 'itemType') }}
{{/each}}
```